# How can I separate whole javaScript numbers and multiply them separately

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is to separate whole numbers like 1986 or 364 and to add them to array like [1000, 900, 80, 6] or [300, 60, 4], it doesn't matter how big or small is number.

```
function convert(num) {
   var numbers = String(num).split("");
   var times = [1000, 100, 10, 1];
   var converted = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
       converted.push(numbers[i] * times[times.length - numbers.length + i]);   
   }
   return converted;
}

convert(360);
```

Comment: Maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the place to ask.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @thefourtheye no it doesn't. This code is not yet working as intended, because it only works for numbers with up to 4 digits. As such this question is **not on-topic** for Code Review, it isn't even off-topic here. Aside from that, a question can by definition not be off-topic at one site, just because it may fit better on another site. Please read up on this on [meta]!

Answer (score 2):

It will work for any number of digits

```js
function convert(num) {
  var temp = num.toString();
  var ans = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    //get the ith character and multiply with correspondng powers of 10
    ans.push(parseInt(temp.charAt(i)) * Math.pow(10, temp.length - i - 1));
  }
  return ans;

}
convert(39323680);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @James Thorpe mentioned, you need to define whats better for you, but this seems to be tidier, and supports any number (not only 4 digits)

```js
function seperateNumber(num) {
  var seperated = [];
  while (num > 0) {
    var mod = num % 10;
    seperated.push(mod);
    num = (num - mod) / 10;
  }
  return seperated;
}

console.log(seperateNumber(1986));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking what if you want convert a higher number?

You could try something like this (not very elegant though):

```js
function convert(num) {
    var numbers = String(num).split("");
    converted = [];
    numbers.reverse();
    numbers.forEach(function(element, index) {
        converted.push(element*Math.pow(10,index));
    });
    return converted.reverse();
}
console.log(convert(19813));
```